# Starting a program on the desktop from SSH in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm logged into my Ubuntu 11.04 box using SSH, and I need to start a program - but it is a Windows GUI program which runs under WINE.

How can I start the program from the SSH terminal so that it opens on the desktop, and then stays open even after I log out of SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general way to start a graphical program from a remote machine:

1. On the target machine run `xhost +`.  (You'll need to do this from a terminal, or from a login script.)
2. from a remote client, SSH into the target machine and run `nohup program &` where "program" is the program as you would run it if you were sitting at the target machine.

Comment: -1 (if I could) for xhost +.  That is just terrible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the program forwarded to your Display connect with `ssh -X`.

But I guess you want to start the program on the remote display?

1. Use `screen` to keep the program open.
2. Start the program with the right user and `DISPLAY` variable of the running X-Session.

For example:

```
xterm -display :1000.0
```

or:

```
DISPLAY=:1000.0 xterm
```

This should work with Wine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `sshd` set up so that it allows X11 forwarding.

Then, just start your GUI as per normal (`nohup` if you want it to run after you log out) and it will appear on your machine.

Edit: if you wanted this to run from an icon (see comment) then you can alias the icon command to

```
ssh fu@bar.com 'nohup MyProgram &'
```

Or just create a small shell script (called ~/bin/runme.sh) on the remote host with this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup MyProgram & 2>&1 $HOME/.nohupp.log
```

and invoke with

```
ssh fu@bar.com ~/bin/runme.sh
```

Comment: I don't want to have the program running on my remote terminal, I actually want it to start up on my server as though I had double-clicked the icon.

Comment: I am not sure I understand: you want a programme installed on a remote server to run on your desktop and not on the remote server?  I have edited my answer to add a icon-like script.

Comment: No, it's not a remote server. The machine is at home and I am at work. I want to start a program on the server as though I was at home sitting in front of the computer, double-clicking the icon on the desktop, however I am not at home, I logged into the terminal via SSH.

Comment: To be clear: on your work machine (aka local) you want an icon that once clicked will start a programme on your home machine (aka remote) but display it on your work machine (aka local).  You home machine (aka remote) will run the programme but you can interact with the GUI displayed on your work machine (aka local).  If that is so, then change the icon to run the shh command above.